What process should we adopt to create our FAQ?
A question was recently asked about what should go in our FAQ.
At present our FAQ is minimal, and I think we should start to make the FAQ a useful part of our site.
But this raises the issue of how to effectively and democratically produce the opening section of the FAQ.
I've had a look at the stats.se FAQ and based on that I put together a proposed initial FAQ for cogsci.se. 
Anyway, I can see various ways of moving forward on the FAQ:
My preferred way would be to post an initial FAQ and then have separate meta threads where users post proposed modifications, additions, and deletions.
Alternatively, we could start with what we have now

Cognitive Sciences - Stack Exchange is for practitioners and research
  professionals of the cognitive sciences.

and simply propose additions, deletions, and modifications to that.

I agree. Piece by piece in separate posts is probably the best way to go.
